# I can't change the Design of items

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am using the ngx-dropzone library however when I drag the files they get very large. In order to get around this, I tried to CSS change the size, but to no avail.

Can anyone help me? I want to have a height and width of about 20px

**HTML**

```
<ngx-dropzone-label>
    <div>
        <h2>My custom dropzone</h2>
    </div>
</ngx-dropzone-label>
<ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
    <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
</ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-dropzone {
    height: 250px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: 5px dashed rgb(235, 79, 79);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can target `ngx-dropzone-preview` like below

```
ngx-dropzone-preview{
    height: 40px !important;
    min-height: 40px !important;
    min-width: 40px !important;
    max-width: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. When I add an image, it always show me the scrollbars and doesn't resize the image to fit into the dropzone. Can anyone provide some solution or idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: @RicardoMagalhães try adding :host ::ng-deep in front of the selector, so the selector would be ":host ::ng-deep ngx-dropzone-preview"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Sarah. I made it work using :host ::ng-deep img

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set the width of the image using this style:

```
:host ::ng-deep img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```